# I am trying to apply these CSS rules to x3 Post-ID's but I can't get it to work - any idea how I can?

Tags: css

I am trying to apply these CSS rules to x3 Post-ID's but I can't get it to work - any idea how I can?

```
.postid-209506 .postid-209512 .postid-209513 {
background: url(.jpg);
}
.postid-209506 .postid-209512 .postid-209513 .entry-title{
   display: none;
}
.postid-209506 .postid-209512 .postid-209513 .entry-header #entry-meta{
    display:none;
}
```

I tried adding them together but it didn't work...

Thanks for all help

Comment: WTF are people downvoting this post? Pretty lame... - what is so bad about my question? Moody-ass people are always on SE I find - is that just my experience?

Comment: Looks like you’ve not asked a good question. What do you expect? First of, you have an insane amount of nested classes, not IDs.

Comment: @henry I can't speak for everyone, but my close vote was because you've asked a pure CSS question, which is [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this stack. The question probably belongs on the [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css) stack.

Answer (score 1):

```
.postid-209506, .postid-209512, .postid-209513 {
background-image: url('.jpg');
}
.postid-209506 .entry-title, .postid-209512 .entry-title, .postid-209513 .entry-title{
   display: none;
}
.postid-209506 .entry-header #entry-meta, .postid-209512 .entry-header #entry-meta, .postid-209513 .entry-header #entry-meta{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: This looks like the appropriate syntax. Great stab in the dark to this question I say!